# AngularJS simple preloader for ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div that shows a preloader. I want to hide that div only after all of my data has finished loading in my ng-repeat.

So far this is what I could piece together but the pieces are not working yet.

Is there another simple way to do this?

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/ilgOZzIy2axSi5Iy85C7?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="location in locations" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">

      {{location.siteName}}

      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="listOfLocations in location.locationsList track by $index">
              {{listOfLocations}}
          </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
App.controller('locationAccordionCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.locations = [
    {
      "siteName":"First Location",
      "locationsList":['First Location 1', 'First Location 2', 'First Location 3']
    },
    {
      "siteName":"Second Location",
      "locationsList":['Second Location 1', 'Second Location 2', 'Second Location 3']
    },
    {
      "siteName":"Third Location",
      "locationsList":['Third Location 1', 'Third Location 2', 'Third Location 3']
    }
  ];

// Hide preloader after repeater is finished loading data
App.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

// hide preloader
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    $scope.hidePreLoader = true;
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can do this

```
    var App = angular.module('App.directives', []);
     App.directive('routeLoadingIndicator', function($rootScope){
       return {
       restrict:'E',
       template:"<h1 ng-if='isRouteLoading'
       style='
       position: fixed;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
       margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px;
       top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
       z-index: 2147483647;
       ' >Loading...</h1>",
       link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
         scope.isRouteLoading = false;

         $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
           scope.isRouteLoading = true;
         });

         $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
           scope.isRouteLoading = false;
         });
       }
     };
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker to show this working? http://plnkr.co/edit/ilgOZzIy2axSi5Iy85C7?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/voIPmpxgiuXmhZlvaZJc?p=preview
modify template as per your needs